# All magnetic quantum numbers are separated by integer steps

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, lie-algebra

The most common *algebraic* derivation of the properties of angular momentum in quantum mechanics follows the usual line of thought.

1. We start with an (unknown) Hilbert space $\mathcal H$ on which there is a triple $\mathbf J=(J_1,J_2,J_3)$ of self-adjoint operators which satisfy $$ [J_i,J_j]=i\epsilon_{ijk}J_k $$(for simplicity, let $\hbar=1$).
2. The operators $J^2=\sum_iJ_i^2$ and $J_\pm=J_1\pm iJ_2$ are defined. We have $[J^2,J_i]=0$, $[J^2,J_\pm]=0$ and $[J_3,J_\pm]=\pm J_\pm$.
3. Since $J_3$ and $J^2$ commute, they have a common eigenbasis written as $$ J^2\varphi_{\lambda,m}=\lambda^2\varphi_{\lambda,m} \\ J_z\varphi_{\lambda,m}=m\varphi_{\lambda,m}, $$with $-\lambda\le m\le \lambda$ thus we can write the decomposition $$ \mathcal H=\bigoplus_\lambda S_\lambda,\quad S_\lambda=\bigoplus_m S_{\lambda,m}, $$where $S_\lambda$ is the eigensubspace of $J^2$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$ and $S_{\lambda,m}$ is the common eigensubspace of $J^2$ and $J_3$ corresponding to $(\lambda,m)$. Although this is not true some of the time, we may suppose that the eigenspaces $S_{\lambda,m}$ are one dimensional and thus spanned by $\varphi_{\lambda, m}$ (take quotients otherwise??? but I think the general argument should work with eigenspaces instead of states).
4. It follows from the restriction $-\lambda\le m\le \lambda$ that for any fixed $\lambda$ we must have a maximum $m_+$ and a minimum $m_-$ eigenvalue, and it follows from the properties of $J_\pm$ that $S_\lambda$ is an invariant subspace of $J_\pm$ and $J_\pm:S_{\lambda,m}\rightarrow S_{\lambda,m\pm1}$. It also follows from some algebraic relations that $m_-=-m_+\equiv j$ and we have $\lambda^2=j(j+1)$
5. The usual argument to show that $j$ is an integer multiple of $1/2$ is that if we take the state $\varphi_{j,m_-}$ belonging to the minimum value $m_-$, then there is a nonnegative integer $k$ such that $J^k_+\varphi_{j,m_-}=C\varphi_{j,m_-+k}\neq 0$ but $J_+^{k+1}\varphi_{j,m_-}=0$. **One then infers that $m_+=m_-+k$, thus $2j=k$ and therefore $j$ is an integer multiple of $1/2$.**

It is this inference that has been highlighted by the use of bold letters that I have a problem with. I see no logical reason why is it that $m_-+k=m_+$. I do not see why it is not possible that there is a number $m^\prime<m_+$ such that $m^\prime$ is an eigenvalue of $J_3$ but $J_+\varphi_{j,m^\prime}=0$.

Alternatively, it is clear that starting from $\varphi_{j,m_-}$, there is a tower of eigenstates $\varphi_{j,m_-+1},\dots,\varphi_{j,m_-+k},\dots$ separated by integer values and terminating after a finite number of elements, but I see no reason why the index of termination should be $m_+$ and that it is not possible that there is a number $\mu$ with $m_-<\mu\neq m_-+k$ ($k$ is an integer) such that there is also a second tower $\varphi_{j,\mu},\varphi_{j,\mu+1},\dots$ "in between" the elements of the first tower, terminating at a different element whose value $\mu_+$ is less than the maximum $m_+$.

If $m_+$ is indeed the maximum then it only follows that *there exists one tower* which terminates at $m_+$, not that *all* towers terminate there.

The question is then how to see that once we have the minimum and maximum eigenvalues $m_-$ and $m_+$, the *only* allowed ones are $m_-+1,m_-+2,\dots,m_+-1,m_+$ (and with $m_+-m_-$ being an integer) instead of having several towers running concurrently?

*Remark*: A similar proof is given when one classifies the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$, however there one explicitly makes the assumptions that 1) each representation space (corresponding to $S_\lambda$ here) is finite dimensional and 2) that each representation is irreducible.

I do not see on what basis would one make these assumptions when discussing angular momentum from a physical point of view, therefore I have *not* made these assumptions. Of course making the above assumptions would resolve my problem but as I have said I want the eigenvalue problem of angular momentum, *not* to classify the irreducible representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$. The two problems might turn out to be equivalent, but they are not so *a priori*.

Comment: I think the proof you mention in your remark does apply to physics. Keep in mind we need a *unitary* representation of $SU(2)$ to represent rotational symmetry; if there was an infinite unitary representation, one could try to build a physical theory of it, but as I understand there is no such representation (eg: https://mathoverflow.net/q/27853/). Even if there was, there's no guarantee that there is a sensible theory using it (this is the case with continuous spin representations of the Poincaire group)

Comment: As for assumption (2), I think this is essentially just a definition. If there was a system described by two different irreducible representations (two towers), I would tend to think of the system as made of two independent pieces.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter%E2%80%93Weyl_theorem

Comment: Your post is long and complicated but it seems you are not using hermiticity (or at the group level unitarity).  This is essential if you want the usual result.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero I used it at the assumption that $S_\lambda$ is spanned by eigenvectors of $J_z$. It still allows for multiple towers of eigenvectors. What further reasoning would imply the usual result?

Comment: you still need $\Gamma(J_+)=\Gamma(J_-)^\dagger$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget what you're trying to do here: The angular momentum algebra is the infinitesimal version of the rotations $\mathrm{SO}(3)$. You're looking for unitary linear representations of the group $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ as its linear representations constitute the projective representations of $\mathrm{SO}(3)$.

All unitary representations are completely reducible and since $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ is compact all of its irreducible representations are finite-dimensional. Thus your additional "assumptions" are not actually assumptions, but just consequences of the compactness of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$.

Comment: Although this anwer along with Andrew 's comment helps me in putting things together, allow me some nitpicking.

As far as I am aware, the usual proofs (either through compactness or semi-simplicity) imply that the *finite dimensional* representations of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb C)$ are completely reducible. If we tentatively accept that this fact is also valid for infinite dimensions, then we can reason as follows.

1) The space $S_\lambda$ is a representation space so it is a direct sum of irreps.
2) The irreps are finite dimensional, and then the proof goes through without a problem...

Comment: ... but is it true that *all* representations (maybe all *unitary* representations) are completely reducible? Well apparantly the above linked Peter-Weyl theorem guarantees that at least the Hilbert space/unitary reps are finite dimensional from the beginning, but I hoped that this result could be established without appealing to what seems like a rather advanced theorem.

Comment: @BenceRacskó That all unitary representations are completely reducible is a general fact: If there is an invariant subspace $V$, then so is $V^\perp$, and hence $V\oplus V^\perp$ is a reduction into subrepresentations. One way to show that all f.d. representations of compact groups are completely reducible is by showing all their representations are unitarizable!

Comment: Of course, i forgot about that. Was mostly thinking about the complete reducibility proof for general representations of semisimple Lie algebras, rather than those of unitary reps.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate the importance of the hermiticity condition, consider the map
\begin{align}
L_+\mapsto \Gamma(L_+)&= e^{-i \phi}\left(j+i \frac{d}{d\phi}\right)\, ,\\
L_-\mapsto \Gamma(L_-)&= e^{+i \phi}\left(j-i \frac{d}{d\phi}\right)\, ,\\
L_z\mapsto \Gamma(L_z)&= i\frac{d}{d\phi}\, .
\end{align}
You can verify that this is a realization of the algebra in the sense that
$$
[L_i,L_j]\mapsto [\Gamma(L_i),\Gamma(L_j)]
$$
The realization $\Gamma$ acts naturally on functions of the form $\Phi_k=e^{-i(j+k)\phi}$ and in fact
\begin{align}
\Gamma(L_-)\Phi_0&=0\, ,\\
\Gamma(L_-)\Phi_k&=-k\Phi_{k-1}\, ,\\
\Gamma(L_+)\Phi_k&=(2j+k)\Phi_{k+1}
\end{align}
for *any* j.  There is no restriction here on the possible $j$'s or the possible $m$'s, and the resulting representation is "legitimate" but fails the hermiticity test as clearly $\Gamma^\dagger(L_+)\ne \Gamma(L_-)$: this representation does not exponentiate to a unitary representation

Thus, hermiticity is *essential* to the argument that the $m$'s are bounded by $\pm j$.

Comment: 1. Mathematicians would recognize this as an explicit construction of a [Verma module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verma_module#The_case_of_sl(2;_C)) of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C})$. 2. Not only does this not "exponentiate to a unitary representation", it has to fail even worse because any strongly continuous representation of SU(2) on a Hilbert space would still be completely reducible, no matter whether it's unitary or not (because it would be unitarizable).

Comment: @ACuriousMind of course there's an intertwiner that is easy to work out, which truncates (aka coset out) and fixes hermiticity in one shot.

Comment: Just in case I came across as criticizing the answer: I didn't mean to imply that anything's wrong here, I just wanted to give additional context. What you're describing in your comment is constructing the usual finite-dimensional representations as quotients of these modules (and that is the theoretical significance of Verma modules of Lie algebras, the irreps usually arise as quotients of them).

Comment: @ACuriousMind Absolutely no harm done whatsoever: I did not take your comment in any way like a criticism.  I myself just wanted to add to your comment about subrepresentations and a way to make the representation unitary.